# CALCULATE HOW MANY 1 IN A GIVEN TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello all in SQL we have to used a query to get a desired output as we want. sometimes we have to write a small and large query to get a same output.

i have a problem statement where i want to calculate a count of 1 in following table:

[image]

i want to calculate a count of sum.

Comment: `SUM()`. and perhaps `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sample data you posted, one option is

```
SQL> with test (a, b, c, d) as
  2    (select 1, 0, 0, 0 from dual union all
  3     select 0, 1, 0, 0 from dual union all
  4     select 0, 0, 1, 0 from dual union all
  5     select 0, 0, 0, 1 from dual
  6    )
  7  select sum(a + b + c + d) result
  8  from test;

    RESULT
----------
         4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are only 0 or 1 then:

```sql
SELECT SUM(A + B + C+ D) AS total
FROM   table_name
```

If your values can be something else then:

```sql
SELECT SUM(
         CASE A WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE B WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE C WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE D WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS total
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, c, d) AS
  SELECT 1, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 0, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 0, 0, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | TOTAL |
> | --- |
> | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=09018ed3fb978c874b0fd8e58590665d)*

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(A,B,C,D)AS
(
  SELECT 1,0,0,0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0,1,0,0 UNION ALL
   SELECT 0,0,1,0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0,0,0,1
)
SELECT SUM
(
  CASE 
     WHEN C.A=1 OR C.B=1 OR C.C=1 OR C.D=1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
)AS CNTT
FROM CTE AS C
```

You can try also this solution

Comment: This counts the number of rows which contain one-or-more `1`s rather than counting the total number of values that are `1`. Also, you do not want the `AS` before the table alias as it is invalid syntax in Oracle and you are missing `FROM DUAL` on each line in the CTE.